# Multiple server backups using kubernetes and rsnapshot

Tags: backup, amazon-s3, kubernetes, rsnapshot

I am looking to setup multiple backups, from multiple servers in different geographical locations at different times using something like a docker/rsnapshot and kubernetes (master + a couple nodes at least). I am pretty familiar with the general layout of how the infrastructure will need to work and the yaml files i'll need to create to identify each server specific characteristics, and the link to an s3 bucket folder for each server... question is, do you think a setup like this is overkill? More servers are on the way so its just 24 right now...

I'm simply trying to automate the process of backing up a growing number of servers to an s3 acct from a single console... thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There is [Velero](https://velero.io/) to backup Kubernetes cluster resources and persistent volumes to S3-compatible storage. You can configure [sync periods](https://velero.io/docs/main/migration-case/#using-backups-and-restores) for backups on a regular basis.